# Java Regex Pattern with atleast one letter

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract an alphanumeric sequence from text. This sequence could be either five or six characters in length, must start and end with a number, and have at least one letter in between, for example: `25D212`, `4WX07`, `8FZW5`, `2T784`, `25XR47`

This is what I was able to put together

```
[0-9][[0-9]|[a-zA-Z]]{3,4}[0-9]
```

The issue with this solution is that it also matches

`888888` (at least one character constraint not being met)

Comment: Please consider bookmarking the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) for future reference.

Comment: You could just check if the string contains a letter,  after applying your pattern.

Comment: @aliteralmind Thanks for the reference link. I am sure it will come handy.

Comment: @phobic Using that as a work around currently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**generalized**
Based on the permutations (below), it looks like it can be generalized to this

```
 # (?i)\d(?=\d{0,3}[a-z])[a-z\d]{3,4}\d

 (?i)
 \d                   # A digit
 (?= \d{0,3} [a-z] )  # a letter in the next 1 to 4 characters
 [a-z\d]{3,4}         # 3 to 4 digits or letters
 \d                   # A digit
```

**permutations**

```
 # (?i)\d(?:[a-z][a-z\d]{2,3}|\d[a-z][a-z\d]{1,2}|\d\d[a-z][a-z\d]{0,1}|\d\d\d[a-z])\d

 (?i)
 \d 
 (?:
      [a-z] 
      [a-z\d]{2,3} 
   |  
      \d 
      [a-z] 
      [a-z\d]{1,2} 
   |  
      \d\d 
      [a-z] 
      [a-z\d]{0,1} 
   |  
      \d\d\d 
      [a-z] 
 )
 \d
```

Input

```
for example: 25D212, 4WX07, 8FZW5, 2T784, 25XR47
```

Output

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 13 , len 6 ) 
25D212  

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 21 , len 5 ) 
4WX07  

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 28 , len 5 ) 
8FZW5  

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 28 , len 5 ) 
8FZW5  

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 42 , len 6 ) 
25XR47
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able solve this with one regex pattern, but you can definately solve it with two patterns.

First pattern will be something like:

```
\d[0-9a-zA-Z]{3,4}\d
```

(Note: `\d` is the same as `[0-9]`)

Second pattern will be this:

```
\d+[a-zA-Z]+\d+
```

The first pattern controls the size of the string, the second confirms that it contains at least one alpha character.

Good resource for testing Java regex patterns: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Looks like the Avinash Raj post is the correct answer. I'm leaving mine as an option (suboptimal as it may be)

Answer (score -1):

@Avinash Raj already has a good-looking pattern, but I wanted to share my alternative:

```
\b(?=[0-9a-zA-Z]{5,6}\b)\d.*[a-zA-Z].*\d\b
```

This may be easier for you to read if you split it apart into the look-ahead assertion that tests for a 5-6 character string of alphanumerics, and the actual pattern that tests the format (of starting and ending with a digit and having a letter somewhere in the middle). This roughly corresponds to how you phrased the question initially, so it may be easier to read and remember going forward "what the heck does *this* do?"

Comment: The main match will overmatch due to `.*`

Comment: @nhahtdh It actually won't. Did you even try it? The lookahead assertion validates that all characters are alpha-numeric. This pattern *does not match*, e.g., `1#,W89`.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/iK3iE4/1. Failed on `02344 sf4` Once you manage to pass assertion, all hells break loose.